# ASP.NET .NET6 System.ArgumentNullException: "Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, .net-6.0, argumentnullexception

I have a TryGetByStatementId method, which, using the `FirstOrDefault` method, returns me the id from the database.

I also have a database that stores information about the uploaded file.
I upload the file through the controller, the file is saved in the file system in wwwroot, and information about it such as id, Name, CreateDateTime are saved in the database.
When I try to delete information using the TryGetByStatementId method, I get an error -> System.ArgumentNullException: "Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name"

The controller with which I download the file and save it to the file system

```
public class ManagementController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext applicationDb;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public ManagementController(ApplicationDbContext applicationDb, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        this.applicationDb = applicationDb;
        _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddFile(IFormFile uploadFile)
    {
        if (uploadFile != null) 
        {
            string path = "/Files/" + uploadFile.FileName;

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + path, FileMode.Create)) 
            {
                await uploadFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

            StatementsDb file = new StatementsDb { StatementsName = uploadFile.FileName, CreateDateTime = DateTime.Now, Path = path}; 

            applicationDb.statementsDbs.Add(file);
            applicationDb.SaveChanges();
        }
        
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Code snippet from the controller with the Remove method

```
public IActionResult RemoveFile(int statementId)
{
    statementsDb.Remove(statementId);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Code snippets from the entity in which I'm trying to get the ID

```
public StatementsDb TryGetByStatementId(int id)
{
    return applicationDb.statementsDbs.FirstOrDefault(statement => statement.StatementsId == id);
}

public void Remove(int statement)
{
    var existingStatement = TryGetByStatementId(statement);
    applicationDb.statementsDbs.Remove(existingStatement);
    applicationDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

Only afterwards, I get the error System.ArgumentNullException: "Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name"

Where did I go wrong?

[UPDATE]

```
using archivingsystem.db;
using archivingsystem.Helpers.AutoMapping;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace archivingsystem
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            IMapper mapper = MappingConfig.RegisterMaps().CreateMapper();

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


            // AutoMapper
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(mapper);
            builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());


            // Services
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IStatementsDbRepository, StatementsDbRepository>();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem like this:

```
public IActionResult RemoveFile(Guid statementId)
    {
        var removeF = statementsDb.TryGetByStatementId(statementId);
        statementsDb.Remove(removeF.StatementsId);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

and

```
public void Remove(Guid statement)
    {
        var fileId = applicationDb.statementsDbs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StatementsId == statement);
        applicationDb.statementsDbs.Remove(fileId);
        applicationDb.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

This error is occurring because the existingStatement variable is `null`. you can add a check for `null` before calling the `Remove` method

```
if (existingStatement != null)
{
    applicationDb.statementsDbs.Remove(existingStatement);
```

Comment: But the TryGetByStatementId method still returns null. I just can't figure out why he can't get the id

Comment: @Vivaldi that you need to find out, why is it returning `null`. do yo have records for your `StatementsId ` in DB?

Comment: I have records, because using the "Add" method I add a record, conditionally it will have Id - 4, my problem is that FirstOrDefault returns null to me when I try to delete this record

Comment: @Vivaldi Can you share how have you registered `ApplicationDbContext `?

Comment: @Vivaldi I mean your startup.cs

Comment: Oh, sure.. Again update

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a problem with your url, you may not get the `statement`, that is to say, the `statement` is always 0, so you cannot get the data. What is your url for the Remove request?

From your current code, your url should look like this:

```
https://localhost:xxx/Management/Remove?statement=1
```

At this point you can see that the `statement` is 1, and the `id` of `TryGetByStatementId` is also 1:

[image]

[image]

If you want to use a url like this：

```
https://localhost:xxx/Management/Remove/2
```

Then you need to add attribute route for `Remove`:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]/{statement:int}")]
```

At this point you can see that the `statement` is 2, and the `id` of `TryGetByStatementId` is also 2:

[image]

[image]

If you can get the `id` correctly, then you should be able to get the corresponding data from the database.